# Does C++ static member variable has different instance in a single process?

Tags: c++

Let us consider a C++ class with one static member variable and two static methods like :

ABC.h

```
class ABC
{
  private:
    static int val;

  public:
    static void set_val(int v);
    static int  get_val();
};
```

ABC.cpp

```
    int ABC::val = 0;
    
    void ABC::set_val(int v) {
          val = v;
    }
    
    int  ABC::get_val() {
         return val;
    }
```

The Class is defined and implemented in a static library : **libabc.a**.

I made an executable object file which links **test.o** and **libabc.a**.

My question is, when I called `ABC::set_val(10)` in **test.o** and called another function, `abc_func()`, in **libabc.a**;
`abc_func()` called `ABC::get_val()` and got a 0.

Why is `ABC::val` not 10?

I thought the scope of a static member variable is the whole process.

I printed the address of `ABC::val` and got 2 different addresses in the functions belonging to **test.o** and **libabc.a**.

Why? I thought **test.o** and **libabc.a** are in the same process, hence the static member variable address should be the same.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It's impossible to answer without seeing [mcve]. Looks like you have two definitions of `int ABC::val`.

Comment: The code you have now posted does not have the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause...
My makefile are complicated and libabc.a has been linked twice...
After I fixed it, ABC::val only has single instance.

Answer (score 5):

You are violating the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule), abetted by a non-standard compiler. Before C++17 you can't have an [definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_data_members) of your static data member within the class definition, and after C++17 you have to define it with the `inline` specifier.

Violating the ODR means your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. I.e. the compiler and linker are not required to emit an error for your program, and the rules of C++ say that it can have any meaning. It looks like your implementation chose to behave as if there were two separate `ABC::val` objects.

Comment: There's surely a definition somewhere, or the linker would fail with an unresolved external error.  OP mentioned printing out the address, that is most definitely ODR-usage and cannot be optimized away.

Comment: @BenVoigt `class ABC { static int val = 0; }` isn't C++. I assume the compiler is treating it as a definition as well as a declaration (as a non-standard extension), and the linker isn't complaining about the duplication

Comment: Specifying an initializer expression inside the class has been allowed since C++11.  It doesn't remove the requirement of a definition.

Comment: @BenVoigt not for static data members

Comment: I modified the code to

class ABC
{
    inline static int val = 0;
....

};

But it looks like still two different instance...

Comment: int ABC::val = 0; in abc.cpp doesn't work either....

Comment: @wiki Why don't you make changes to get the code to the point where you think it is required by the standard to work but doesn't and post it as a new question.